# How to position circles/points at intersection on a Radar Chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radar-chart

I am working on a Radar chart. I have appended some circles that I am trying to position at intersections. However, there seems to be something wrong with the `cx and cy` attributes of the circles, which I am unable to figure out.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

```js
var dataset = [{
  "day": 1,
  "sales": 40
}, {
  "day": 2,
  "sales": 85
}, {
  "day": 3,
  "sales": 70
}, {
  "day": 4,
  "sales": 30
}, {
  "day": 5,
  "sales": 85
}, {
  "day": 6,
  "sales": 60
}, {
  "day": 7,
  "sales": 85
}, {
  "day": 8,
  "sales": 35
}, {
  "day": 9,
  "sales": 70
}, {
  "day": 10,
  "sales": 15
}];

var w = 460,
  h = 460;
var margin = {
  top: 20,  bottom: 10,  left: 10,  right: 10
};
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var circleConstraint = d3.min([height, width]);
var radius = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, (circleConstraint / 2)]);
var centerXPos = width / 2 + margin.left;
var centerYPos = height / 2 + margin.top;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + centerXPos + ", " + centerYPos + ")");
//Adds circular gridLines and labels
var gridLines = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100];
var circleAxes = svg.selectAll(".circularGrid")
  .data(gridLines)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "circularGrid");
circleAxes.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return radius(d);
  })
  .style("stroke", "#CCC")
  .style("fill", "none");
circleAxes.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dy", function(d) {
    return radius(-d - 1);
  })
  .text(String)
  .style("font-size", "10pt")
  .style("font-family", "sans-serif");

//Append path for salesLine
var sales = [];
dataset.forEach(function(d) {
  sales.push(d.sales);
});
svg.selectAll(".salesLine")
  .data([sales])
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "salesLine")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "#000")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line.radial()
    .radius(function(d) {
      return radius(d);
    })
    .angle(function(d, i) {
      return (i / dataset.length) * 2 * Math.PI;
    }));
// Appending circles at intersections
svg.selectAll(".datapoints")
  .data(dataset).enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "datapoints")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .style("fill", "#4393c3")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return radius(d.day);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return radius(d.sales);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify the question a little bit? Are you trying to position the dots on the intersections between lines and circles?

Comment: @nick - Apologies for the confusion. I just wanted to place the dots on the line/path, similar to a scatter plot that is connected with a line. Forget the gray circles, those are just grid-lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the code, you should implement little bit of trigonometry:

```
// Appending circles at intersections
svg.selectAll(".datapoints")           // it doubles line [*]
  .data(dataset).enter()
  .append("svg:circle")                // full notation for the node
  .classed({"datapoints": true})       // [*] selection.classed() method for classes,
                                       // but you can omit this line because you wrote .selectAll(".datapoints") above
  .attr({"r": 10, "fill": "#4393c3"})  // you must make big dots 
                                       // to be clickable for people
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
        var alpha = (2 * Math.PI / dataset.length) * i;
        return( radius(d.sales) * Math.cos(alpha - Math.PI / 2) ); // just as in trigonometry book
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
        var alpha = (2 * Math.PI / dataset.length) * i;
        return( radius(d.sales) * Math.sin(alpha - Math.PI / 2) );
  })
  .on("click", function(d){
        alert("$" + d.sales);
  })                                // now you can click on it to see the sales value
  .on("mouseover", function(d){     // little kiss of animation
    d3.select(this).attr("r", "14");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d){
    d3.select(this).attr("r", "10");
  });
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/jitepuhitu/1/

DEMO (animation): http://jsbin.com/niculecuzo/2/

Comment: I recommend you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system and https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/parametric_equations/polar_coor/v/polar-coordinates-1 And you know, everything starts from mathematic.

Comment: I will look into these. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to draw data points like markers:

DEMO:
http://jsbin.com/sepunibove/2/

By the way, multiple `.attr()` lines:

```
.attr("class", "datapoints")
.attr("r", 3)
```

you can write like single associative array:

```
.attr({"class": "datapoints", "r": 3})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rubin, this will do as well. I was just wondering if you know a way to reposition the dots using `cx and cy` attributes, like I was doing in my code? It is quite simple on a line chart, but I was just not able to reposition them on the radar chart because of its polar coordinates I guess.